# tsql clash: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with tinyint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have  `[A-NEST BY]` and `[A-CUT BY]` field both are `datetime` fields why do i get when i run an update

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure NSTBY, Line 9 Operand type
>   clash: date is incompatible with tinyint

```
SET [A-NEST BY] = 
    case DateAdd( day, -10, t1.[A-CUT BY] )
         when 7 then DateAdd( day, -2, t1.[A-CUT BY] )
         when 1 then DateAdd( day, -3, t1.[A-CUT BY])
        else  t1.[A-CUT BY]-10
    end,

    FROM WORKORDERS T1
         INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
        END
```

Comment: `case DateAdd( day, -10, t1.[A-CUT BY] ) when 7` doesn't make sense, DateAdd will give you a new date, how are you expecting to compare it to 7?

Comment: @artm  I used similar logic and It works fine I used set datestart =7  7 is Sunday here

Comment: Do you mean `CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, -10, t1.[A-CUT BY]))...` ?

Comment: The idea is if the nest date is Sunday move the date to Friday otherwise set a-nest date =cut-by-1

Comment: As an example, if `[A-CUT BY]` is '2017-04-04', 10 days prior would be '2017-03-25' (a Saturday). Do you then want to make `[A-NEXT BY]` '2017-03-24' or '2017-03-31'?

Comment: @zKL thank you i want to see `'2017-03-24'`

Answer (score 0):

The actual logic to make your query work would be something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET [A-NEST BY] = 
    DATEADD
    (
        DAY, 
        -CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, t1.[A-CUT BY]) 
            WHEN 3 -- For Tuesday, ten days prior is a Saturday, so take an extra day off.
            THEN 11 
            WHEN 4 -- For Wednesday, ten days prior is a Sunday, so take an extra two days off.
            THEN 12 
            ELSE 10 -- Default to ten days.
            END,
        t1.[A-CUT BY]
    )
FROM WORKORDERS T1
INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
```

That said, it looks like you're making this a trigger.

If this is, for example, an insert trigger on your WORKORDERS table, I would suggest rather than using a trigger, you use a computed column (unless the [A-NEST BY] date can change).

Comment: thanks @ZLK sorry for the delay  the 7th date is Saturday the 1st date is Sunday, if sunday or saturday move to friday otherwise  `SET [A-NEST BY] =t1.[A-CUT BY]-1` i am a little bit confused about the Tuesday and Wednesday part on your comment

Comment: @Joe, 10 days before Tuesday is a Saturday. e.g. 2017-04-04 is a Tuesday, 10 days before is 2017-03-25, therefore you take 11 days off instead and make it 2017-03-24. For 2017-04-05 (Wednesday), you take 12 days off and make it 2017-03-24.

Comment: yes but the dates are always changed it doesn't matter?

Comment: No, it will look at the [A-CUT BY] and check whether it should be 10, 11 or 12 days based on [A-CUT BY]. The specific date doesn't matter. e.g. for any Tuesday, 10 days back is a Saturday so it'll go 11 days back. For any Wednesday, 10 days back is a Sunday so it'll go 12 days back. For every other day, 10 days back is a weekday.